# C# Reflection method GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance) not returning child class objects

Tags: c#, reflection

I am attempting to retrieve the child classes of an object while omitting primitive types.

```
   public class Dog
    {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Name {get;set;}
    public Breed Breed {get;set;}
    }
```

var dog = new Dog();
var children = dog.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance);

Why does the children array not contain the breed property?

Comment: Try to use `BindingFlags.Instance`  with `BindingFlags.Public` like this:
`var children = dog.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);`
or with pair `BindingFlags.Public` and `BindingFlags.NonPublic` like this:
`var children = dog.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By supplying only `BindingFlags.Instance`, you can't get any properties at all, because you are not sending any access modifier predicate.

According to your needs, combine these flags with bitwise OR operator `|`

You can find the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.8

```
var children = dog.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

EDIT:

Unfortunately, the enumeration does not have any value for filtering the properties according to their value types. To make this a complete answer, the filtering to an array containing only the `Breed` property is as contributed by @const-phi:

```
var result = children.Where(c => c.PropertyType.IsClass).ToArray(); // Const Phi
```

Comment: Your answer returns all properties, and my goal is to return only the breed property. Isn't that what the Instance constraint is for?

Comment: Then (how can I see) you should use filter like this: `var result = children.Where(c => c.PropertyType.IsClass).ToArray();`

Comment: No. There are no constraints for property type. You should filter the results. And @constphi has already neatly put it as a simple linq statement

Comment: Thank you Const Phi, this is what I needed.